# Windows Server 2012 Forest and Domain functional levels compatibility

Tags: sql, windows-server-2012, sccm, scom

I'm using a Windows 2003 domain, and a currently planning for a Windows Server 2012 upgrade, so I'm looking at all software which could be hurted by a Domain (and Forest) functional level raise to Windows Server 2012 level.
Could you please tell me if you ever had good or bad experiences about such case for following products:
 - SQL Server 2000 (and also all higher versions until 2012)
 - SCOM 2007 R2
 - SharePoint 2007 (and 2010)
 - SCCM (version unknow, what's the minimum?)

I keep searching for such information with no success, so I count on all of your experience to share this information, may it be useful for other, it will be for me.

Answer (score 4):

None of these products will be impacted by the raising of the forest or domain functional levels.

I can't think of a single application that would be impacted by this, as it typically only increases the number of features present in Active Directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not able to find any "official" note from Microsoft, about this. Would you have any?

Comment: I doubt it. Since FFLs and DFLs don't impact these applications, Microsoft has no reason to publish an article stating that. That would be like asking someone at the train station to verify that you eating an ice cream sandwich will not cause your train to be delayed.